# Locally finite measures on a Polish space form a Polish space

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

I am looking for a reference where the following question is answered (hopefully affirmatively):

Let $S$ be a Polish space (maybe one needs to assume local compactness?). Is the space of locally finite measures on $S$ (e.g. with the topology of vague convergence) again a Polish space?
If yes, is there a simple characterization of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of the latter space?

Thanks!

EDIT: By vague convergence I mean that $\mu_n\to \mu$ if for all continuous functions $f$ with compact support we have $\int f\mathrm d\mu_n \to \int f \mathrm d\mu$.

Comment: What is the topology of vague convergence here? Locally finite measures do not really represent any dual space.

Comment: Your current definition of vague convergence doesn't make sense.  Do you mean all **continuous** functions with compact support?  If so, then you certainly need something like local compactness. On something like an infinite-dimensional Banach space, the only continuous compactly supported function is 0, and hence the topology you described is the trivial topology which is certainly not Polish.

Comment: yes, sorry. I meant continuous with compact support of course

Comment: It's clear that a continuous function with compact support on $X$ is zero at every $x$ with no compact neighborhood. For instance, on an infinite-dimensional Banach space, there is no nonzero such function, and the space of measures is not Hausdorff (it has the indiscrete topology). So it's indeed very reasonable to assume $X$ locally compact.

Comment: In a Polish space that is not locally compact, there may be no nonzero continuous functions with compact support.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes. If you assume to have a locally compact Hausdorff space and consider only *positive* measures then the space of locally finite measures with vague topology is Polish.

This can be found e.g. in Dawson's "Superprocesses at Saint-Flour", in the section dedicated to random measures (pp. 40 and onwards).

As for the Borel $\sigma-$Field I believe that in the same section you can find results regarding the finite (vs *locally* finite) case. Maybe they extend directly. Otherwise you might need to be more clear about what characterization you want.